# Gruntfile.js won't convert SASS file when it sees a change

Tags: sass, gruntjs

I am trying to set up grunt to automatically compile my SCSS to CSS.
I started by installing Sass using Ruby, then I installed Grunt and I have it running with this gruntfile.js:

**gruntfile.js**

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        sass: {
            dist: {
                files: {
                    'mysite/static/css/grunt.css' : 'mysite/static/sass/_video.scss'
                }
            }
        },
        watch: {
            css: {
                files: '**/*.scss',
                tasks: ['sass']
            }
        }
    });
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.registerTask('default',['watch']);
}
```

When I run the command:

> grunt watch

Grunt runs and watches for any changes in my file and it will see the change, but never converts the SCSS to CSS.

```
dominic@dom-Inspiron-7559:~/Desktop/Projects/stemletics/stemletics/mysite$ grunt watch
Running "watch" task
Waiting...
>> File "mysite/static/sass/_video.scss" changed.
Running "sass:dist" (sass) task

Done.
Completed in 0.517s at Sun Oct 28 2018 22:36:47 GMT-0400 (EDT) - Waiting...
```

I am using this guide: http://ryanchristiani.com/getting-started-with-grunt-and-sass/

Comment: According to the console output you have logged, the correct `sass:dist` task is executing upon change of `mysite/static/sass/_video.scss`. You should check that running the `sass:dist` tasks is actually doing what you want (i.e compiling your SCSS)

Answer (score 0):

try below setting

```
grunt.initConfig({
  sass: {
    dev: {
      src: ['mysite/static/sass/_video.scss'],
      dest: 'mysite/static/css/grunt.css',
    },
  },
  watch: {
    sass: {
      files: ['mysite/static/sass/*.scss'],
      tasks: ['sass'],
    },
    livereload: {
      options: { livereload: true },
      files: ['mysite/**/*'],
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: Hi Shiv, I changed my code and obtained the same results